# How am I able to create A List<T> containing an open generic Interface?

Tags: c#, list, generics, interface

I have a List which must contain `IInteract` Objects. But `IInteract` is a generic interface which requires 2 type arguments.

My main idea is iterate through a list of Objects and "Interact" one with another if they didn't interact yet.
So i have this object

```
List<IObject> WorldObjects = new List<IObject>();
```

and this one:

```
private List<IInteract> = new List<IInteract>();
```

Except I can't compile the last line because `IInteract` requires 2 type arguments. But I don't know what the arguments are until I add them. I could add interactions between Objects of Type A and A... or Objects of Type B and C.

I want to create "Interaction" classes which do something with the "acting" object and the "target" object, but I want them to be independent from the objects... so I could add an Interaction between for instance... **"SuperUltraClass"** and... an **"integer"**.

Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of your interfaces?  I'm not sure I really understand the question.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is simulate interactions in my own "virtual world". And I want them to interact as I say by including my own series of "interactions". Each object has its own thread, and so does the world. This is just a test, I want each object work at a pace, and every update happens within each "world" cycle. The thing is: I want to "include" interactions between types of objects whenever i find necessary. So I could add two "OlympicRunner" classes and put them to race. Or I could add a "OlympicRunner" and a "Waitress" and put them to talk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming IInteract is defined as something like

```
interface IInteract<T1, T2>
```

and you are using it for a field of a class Foo:

```
class Foo
{
  List<IInteract...> field;
}
```

Then if you want to defer the decision of what types to bind to the IInteract type arguements you need to parameterize the container class:

```
class Foo<T1, T2>
{
   List<IInteract<T1, T2>> field;
}
```

The type arguments to IInteract here will be bound when you define a concrete instantiation of the container class, like:  `var x = new Foo<int, double>().`  This will cause the IInteract field to be of type `IInteract<int, double>` for that particular instantiation of the Foo generic type.

Comment: But then when I instantiated the class I would be tied to these two types, correct? I want the list to store IInteract<T1,T2> of different types.

Comment: Yes, the IInteract interface would be bound to those two types, but only for that particular instantiation of the container class.  If you have another pair of types T3 and T4, you can instantiate another instance of the container class and that instance's IInteract will be bound to T3 and T4.  You can instantiate the container class and thus bind the IInteract interface to virtually unlimited number of types.

Comment: If you mean that you want to be able to put T1,T2 into the IInteract object instance at runtime, then switch gears to put T3,T4 into the same IInteract instance, then generics aren't going to help you.  Generics provide a way to defer type decisions, but the end result is still a concrete type that is bound to specific T1,T2 types.  You can have multiple concrete instantiations of the same generic type bound to different T1,T2 type params, but you can't mix and match different types in the same concrete instantiation.

Comment: An alternative to the previous scenario (switching gears in mid stream to put instances of T3, T4 into the IInteract<T1,T2>) is to use plain old OOP polymorphism techniques.  Define all the classes that you will be putting into the IInteract as decendents of a common ancestor type, or all implement a common interface, then specify that common ancestor or interface type as your T1/T2 type params for IInteract.  Generics don't really buy you much in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I think an interface hierarchy might make things easier.  The top-level could be a non-generic interface with just the methods that you need to invoke, absent any type information.  The second level would be those that required some typing...of course, it may be enough to simply have the implementing class instead of the second level interface.

```
public interface IInteract
{
    void Interact();
}

public interface IInteract<TActor,TTarget> : IInteract
{
    TActor Actor { get; set; }
    TTarget Target { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create your list of `IInteract` objects and it can contain any of the strongly typed `IInteract<TActor,TTarget>` objects, though only those methods on the non-generic interface will be available.  The important thing will be the concrete implementations -- that is what will determine what code gets executed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container (I've used [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) in the past).  Then you can do something like this:

```
void Interact<TA, TB>(TA objectA, TB objectB)
{
    var interact = Container.Resolve<IInteract<TA, TB>>();
    interact.Interact(objectA, objectB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish.  What you need to do is create a concrete class which implements your interface, and then use that in your List<>.  Like so:

```
public interface IInteract
{
   Type A { get; set; }
   Type B { get; set; }
}


public class Interact : IInteract
{
    public Type A
    {
        get { return a; }
    }

    public Type B
    {
        get { return b; }
    }

}
```

And then use your concrete class in your list:

```
private List<Interact> = new List<Interact>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
private List<IInteract<SomeType, SomeOtherType>> = new List<IInteract<SomeType, SomeOtherType>>();
```

But like you said you don't know what types you're adding. So here are a couple of options:

1: Use `object` (or even `dynamic`) types:

```
private List<IInteract<object, object>> ...
```

2: Use generics in your class:

```
class Foo<T1, T2> {
    private List<IInteract<T1, T2>> ...
}

...

Foo<string, int> bar = new Foo<string, int>();
```

In the second example you are locked into adding only strings and ints (or whatever you create the Foo object to be) to your list. In the first example you can mix and match, but you would have to do runtime type checking to figure out what you're pulling out of the list.

Comment: Option 1 will only work if IInteract is covariant in T1 and T2

Comment: Option 1 seems what I need, but it doesn't work neither with object or dynamic. How am i supposed to cast?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a dictionary, where the key is a tuple of the two types that you are interacting, and the values are Interact, so each Interact implementation would have to do some casting

```
private Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, IInteract<Object, Object>> interactions = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, IInteract<Object, Object>>();
```

It's a bit messy but then you can add to it:

```
IInteract<Object, Object> superClassIntInteraction = someInteractionClass;
interactions.Add(new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof(SuperClass),typeof(int)), superClassIntInteraction);
```

I'm assuming that you want to be able to search the list/dictionary to be able to find a specific interaction later on, which is where the dictionary comes in handy