# List of Generics T using Interface

Tags: c#, list, generics

Following these two SO questions:

[Is it possible to use a list of untyped generics in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613857/is-it-possible-to-use-a-list-of-untyped-generics-in-c?lq=1)

and

[How am I able to create A List<T> containing an open generic Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521587/how-am-i-able-to-create-a-listt-containing-an-open-generic-interface)

```
  public interface IValue
{
    object Min { get; set; }
    object Max { get; set; }
    object Avg { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Value<T> : IValue
{
     abstract T Min;
     abstract T Max;
     abstract T Avg;
    object IValue.Avg { get { return Avg; } }
    object IValue.Min { get { return Min; } }
    object IValue.Max { get { return Max; } }

    public Value(T min, T max, T avg)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max= max;
        Avg = avg;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in code....

```
Value myValue = new Value<ulong>(x, y, z);
Value myValue = new Value<ushort>(x, y, z);
List<IValue> myList = new List<IValue>();
myList.add(myValue);
//Do stuff like myList[0].Min
```

I can't get this to work properly. I Imagine it has to do with my interface and how I'm using it. I want to be able to call a constructor and set the values however I need to.

I get errors like "modifier 'abstract' not valid on fields. Try a property instead" and "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class of interface Value" but I also can't do new IValue either.

Comment: Would an abstract property work for you? Why is Value abstract, anyway? Looks pretty concrete to me.

Comment: <ulong> was one example. I might use <ushort> as well or <int> and vice versa.

Comment: @user999999928 That does not change the fact that an abstract type wouldn’t be neccessary for that. It’s generic, so it can take different type arguments without being abstract.

Comment: Ah right sorry misunderstood. The point being was that I wanted to make a List<Value<T>> which according to the other SO, you would want to make an interface which had abstract values in the Value class.

Comment: The [question you’re referring to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613857/is-it-possible-to-use-a-list-of-untyped-generics-in-c) had an abstract type to begin with; it’s not necessary to make a list of an interface type.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use *abstract* at all? If you want to *create class instances* the class can't be *abstract*.

```
public class Value<T>: IValue {
  // Better to name these fields as "min, max, ave" or "m_Min, m_Max, m_Ave"
  T Min;
  T Max;
  T Avg;

  // Do not forget about "set" accessors
  object IValue.Avg {
    get { return Avg; }
    set { Avg = (T) value; }
  }

  object IValue.Min {
    get { return Min; }
    set { Min = (T) value; }
  }

  object IValue.Max {
    get { return Max; }
    set { Max = (T) value; }
  }

  public Value(T min, T max, T avg) {
    Min = min;
    Max = max;
    Avg = avg;
  }
}

...

// "Value<ulong> myValue" instead of "Value myValue "
Value<ulong> myValue = new Value<ulong>(x, y, z);
List<IValue> myList = new List<IValue>();
myList.Add(myValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, you were correct. I didn't want abstract at all. I was just trying to follow the other question linked when I made the mistake of misreading. But when I tried without abstract, I still couldn't do newValue<ulong>(x,y,z) Then, after your response, it hit me that I wasn't doing set { Min = (T) value). That solved the whole thing. I now have a proper list of Value generics.

Answer (score 5):

- You can’t create an object of an interface, so you can’t do `new IValue()`.
- You can’t create an object of an abstract type, so you can’t do `new Value<SomeType>()` either.
- In `Value<T>`, `Min`, `Max` and `Avg` are *fields*, and fields cannot be abstract. You want to make properties instead:

  ```
  public abstract T Min { get; set; }
  public abstract T Max { get; set; }
  public abstract T Avg { get; set; }
  ```
- You probably don’t want to use `abstract` at all. `Value<T>` looks pretty complete, and given that you expect to be able to create it, there is no reason to have it as an abstract type.

Comment: Your last point isn't the case.  There are no possible types that can be used as a generic argument that cannot be implicitly cast to `object`, so that part will work fine.  Yes, it doesn't provide access to the underlying types of each of those values, but if he doesn't need that, then his code will still work.  He could provide strongly typed access outside of the interface if he wanted, but it's not *needed* for what he's shown so far.

Comment: @Servy If you explicitely implement it, yes. But if you just try to have `T Min` as the implementation of the interface’s `object Min` then that won’t work.

Comment: But that's *not* what he did.  If you look at the actual code in the question, he properly implements the interface.  Your pointing out a mistake that he explicitly didn't make.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I did point out that OP implemented the interface explicitely. I also pointed out that in the original code, the interface was misnamed (thus, OP wasn’t properly implementing `IValue`). I removed that section now though as apparently pointing out things that OP likely knows confuses people…

Comment: Yes sorry for the misnamed Statistic value. I fixed it in the OP before seeing your response. The abstract was throwing me off, as I was just following what the other SO Question had done without realizing his class was initially abstract. Silly of me. I didn't want abstract at all in this case. When removing the abstract though, I was still having issues getting the new Value(x,y,z) working when I realized that my set methods was messed up too.